# Json object in Rails view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I have a search page on a rails app. The Search controller fetches the spaces based on a query in the model, and returns them as json. I'm using $.getJSON in a view to fetch them:

Search Controller:

```
respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    @spaces = Space.find_spaces(params)
  end
```

Space model

```
def self.find_spaces(params = {})
  params ||= {}
  spaces = Space.all
  spaces = spaces.near(params[:location], 10) if params[:location].present?
  # spaces = space.where("name LIKE ? ", params[:name]) if params[:name].present?
  spaces = spaces.where("description LIKE %?%" , params[:description]) if params[:description].present?
  spaces
end
```

Script (views/search/index.html.erb)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#search_form" ).submit(function() {
        // clear out current results first
        $('#spaces').empty();
        // fetch all results
    $.getJSON( "/search.json", $('#search_form').serialize())
    .done(function( data ) {
            $.each(data, function(key, space) {
                $('#spaces').append("<h1>" + space.name +  "</h1><p>" + space.description + "</p>");
            });
        });
    }).trigger('submit'); //this is to submit on page load if coming from home page
});
```

This is all working fine, and I can access the JSON object, and display it in the view using jquery, and it all updates without refresh as expected, with the right results based on the form/query.

My question is regarding working with the Json data in the view.

Am I doing this right? Seems a bit silly, as now I can't use any Rails helpers (for instance link helpers) in my view, as it's just javascript/json object. I don't want to end up appending a horrible mess of html with object ids etc to create links.

Is there a proper/better way I should be doing this? I've read through the docs and a few other tutorials, but nowhere really (at all) describes the best way of working with returned Json in a view. Should I be using partials? .js.erb files? Magic?

Thanks for any enlightenment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ajax to get JSON data, you could actually use ajax to get the entire rendered HTML and simply append the whole result into #spaces. First create a new action in your controller

Search Controller:

```
def result
  @spaces = Space.find_spaces(params)
end
```

route.rb

```
match "search/result" => "search#result"
```

Then your view views/search/result.html.erb

```
<% @spaces.each do |space| %>
<h1><%= space.name %></h1><p><%= space.description %></p>
<% end %>
```

now you can use ajax to get the rendered view from rails and put it whole using javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#search_form" ).submit(function() {
        $('#spaces').empty();
        $.get( "/search/result", $('#search_form').serialize())
        .done(function( search_result_html ) {
            $("#spaces").html( search_result_html );
        });
    }).trigger('submit'); //this is to submit on page load if coming from home page
});
```

That way you render everything at view/search/result.html.erb and use whatever rails helper you want

Comment: Thanks for this, explained nicely. Nowhere in the docs does it really go into detail of the flow like that.